# Combining the results for two rows of data

Tags: business-objects

I'm finding my away around SAP BO 4.3 SP2. I've been given a universe to retrieve data which I've created a query for and retrieved the results. Everything looks good, apart from 2 rows of data which I would like to combine displaying one row of data.

Is this possible to do on the table using the BO GUI without having to delve into SQL?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshot of your data or some sample data that is similar? Is every value in the 2 rows of data the same?